# Hyperstack add dynamic class to manual class names

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperstack

I need to add a dynamic class to some regular classes while updating syntax for Hyperstack:

```
div.upload_header.text_left(class: ('uploaded' if 
FileUploads.complete?)) do
```

Should become something like this:

```
DIV(class: 'upload-header text-left (dynamic 'uploaded' should go 
here)') do
```

I just can't seem to figure out how/if regular and dynamic classes can be declared together.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to add some precision to your question. What is your problem, what have you tried and what is your question. Please see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: FYI matt the old haml style (i.e. `div.upload_header`) is deprecated so you want to get rid of that stuff anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String interpolation can be done conditionally:

```rb
DIV(class: "upload-header text-left #{'uploaded' if FileUploads.complete?}")
```

The class parameter can also accept an array:

```rb
def upload_header_classes
  ['upload-header', 'text-left'].tap do |classes|
    classes << 'uploaded' if FileUploads.complete?
  end
end

DIV(class: upload_header_classes)
```

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do it too, this is ruby!